# How to get minimum/maximum latitude and longitude from a MapView?

Tags: android, google-maps, android-mapview, android-maps, bounding-box

Currently I am using the following code to get the minimum and maximum latitude and longitude from a (Google Maps) MapView object.

```
GeoPoint center = map.getMapCenter();
Double minLat = (center.getLatitudeE6() - (map.getLatitudeSpan() / 2)) / 1E6;
Double minLong = (center.getLongitudeE6() - (map.getLongitudeSpan() / 2)) / 1E6;
Double maxLat = (center.getLatitudeE6() + (map.getLatitudeSpan() / 2)) / 1E6;
Double maxLong = (center.getLongitudeE6() + (map.getLongitudeSpan() / 2)) / 1E6;
```

Unfortunately, this is not giving me a correct output. I am currently at zoom level 18 in the MapView, centred on the point **(52.9476, -1.1452)**. The output of the above code gives the values **(52.947632, -181.145156, 52.947632, 178.854844)** respectively. Obviously there is an issue here in that the minimum latitude shown is a physical impossibility, and the latitudes are both exactly the same as the centre latitude. I can confirm that the MapView itself is showing the location correctly.

Can anyone explain why this is happening? Of all the solutions to this issue I have seen, this is the only one that people seem to have had any luck with and it still doesn't work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've now solved this issue myself. Essentially, before the Projection of the MapView is ready, these functions will respectively return 0 and 360*1E6 for latitude and longitude. As such, all that needs to be done is in an AsyncTask perform checks on these values until they have been prepared.